# webpack4 hot reloading not working for some files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

I have a problem with react webpack4 when i try to hot reload the changes fom certain files. And those files where the ones i modified from its original path (/from /src/containers to /src/components)
Rest of files reloading working well...
Code of my webpack config file is below:

```
  const path = require('path');
  const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
  const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

  const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
  });

  module.exports = {
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, './'),
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "html-loader",
              options: { minimize: true }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "style-loader"
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                sourceMap: true,
                minimize: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html"
      }),
      new Dotenv()
    ],
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you share the error log, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can share the error log, I may tell what is the real problem. But current config is missing for an entry point. If your application is a **single page app**, do it like the following code;

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  ...
}
```

if you are building **multi page application** do it like the following code;

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pageOne: path.join(__dirname, "src", "pageOne", "index.js"),
    pageTwo: path.join(__dirname, "src", "pageTwo", "index.js"),
    pageThree: path.join(__dirname, "src", "pageThree", "index.js")
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!
Tho i wasnt able to fix it. There is not error log actually. Everything compiles successfully and "works". However, its like the app holds some cache for the removed files (changed their directory path) and those files when I make some changes, the page doesnt reload them, but others yes, they reflect the changes on hot reloading.

Comment: I tried with your config on my boilerplate project. It is working properly with entry point property. I am not an expert on hot reload but it should work when you change the file not file directory. After changing the directory of the file, just change import codes with the new directory. Then it should refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here and having this issue, I had this exact problem where files in my 'src/components' directory weren't hot reloading.

I was able to fix it when I saw in the log that webpack was looking for the directory 'src/Components' for some reason, so I changed the name of the components directory to something totally different like 'placeholder' then changed it back to 'components' and ran a fresh install.